# startup/shutting down screen showing Xubuntu's bootsplash and not Ubuntu's

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, plymouth

I installed Xubuntu-desktop over Ubuntu 11.10 and now when I shutdown my system or start it up, I see Xubuntu's bootsplash screen. Is simply removing the plymouth theme for Xubuntu corrects the problem and brings back default Ubuntu's? I don't want to 'experiment' thereby breaking something during the process.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following commands

```
# Select your desired plymouth theme
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth

# Rebuild / update your initramfs with the new theme
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

If you prefer a graphical tool you can try plymouth manager, it is available via a ppa

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mefrio-g/plymouthmanager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plymouth-manager
```

There are several themes available in the same ppa

https://launchpad.net/~mefrio-g/+archive/plymouthmanager

[image: plymouth manager]

Comment: OK, this resolved the problem during shutdown but now i don't see anything while the laptop is booting up.